# Should I stop using HTML event handler attributes

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

Should I stop using HTML event handler attributes and start using `addEventListener()` all the time?

Example:

```
<button id="mybutton">Click me</button>
<script>
     var b = document.getElementById("mybutton");
     b.onclick = function() { alert("Thanks for clicking me!"); };
     b.addEventListener("click", function() { alert("Thanks again!"); }, false);
</script>
```

I mean should I stop using `onclick`, `onchange` etc. and start using `addEventListener()` instead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Should" leads to opinion-based answers. :-)

Objectively, advantages to using `addEventListener` are:

1. You can have more than one handler for the same event on the same element.
2. You can more effectively decouple your JavaScript from your HTML. There's still coupling, indirectly through structural or other selectors to finding the elements, but at least the HTML no longer has any knowledge of the JavaScript. By defining a contract between the HTML and JavaScript (for instance, buttons that need to add things have an `add-btn` class or some such), you can have different teams working on the HTML and JavaScript without either needing to know more than the contract.

The disadvantage is that unless you use a library that abstracts-away browser differences for you, unless you can ignore IE8 (and as it's still used by a huge number of people [Net Applications says [21.7% as of Nov 2013](http://marketshare.hitslink.com/browser-market-share.aspx?qprid=2&qpcustomd=0); [Stat Counter says 8.65%](http://gs.statcounter.com/#browser_version-ww-monthly-201211-201311)], only niche sites can ignore it), you have to handle the `addEventListener` / `attachEvent` hassle yourself. That's easy, one `hookEvent` function or similar that you use, but it's a disadvantage.

Comment: Those stats (all those stats are totally useless I know) look odd to me. [WikiMedia](http://stats.wikimedia.org/wikimedia/squids/SquidReportClients.htm) only reports about 4 - 5% IE8 usage. Also Chrome usage looks a bit low @ that marketshare link.

Comment: @PeeHaa: I tried to include StatCounter for balance, as Net Apps and Stat Counter are two of the most well-respected sites for this sort of info and they tend to have different numbers (different methodology, different sampling), but it wasn't working for me at the time. (It is now and I've added it -- 8.65% is still too much to ignore, and of course, Net Apps could have the more accurate number.) FWIW, Net Applications (my first source) is what Microsoft uses for http://ie6countdown.com. Remember IE8 is the best Windows XP can do, we'll be stuck with it a while.

Comment: (Of course, if you're stuck on Windows XP for whatever reason, the *best* you can do isn't IE8, it's: Install just about anything from Mozilla, Google, or Opera. :-) But these sticks in the mud tend to be large corporates with lock-down policies...)

Comment: Yeah I know. Wasn't meant to degrade your answer in any way. Just wanted to give OP the complete picture. The only thing those stats are good for are the ability of seeing trends, but that's about it. If OP (or somebody else for that matter) wants to know its audience he/she should just track it in their own site.

Comment: Agreed. I think those stats are worth a *bit* more than just spotting trends, but I agree: Fundamentally, pay attention to your real traffic and address what you see.